# Generate JSON log from NGINX-1.14.0

Tags: json, nginx, logging

1.https://github.com/jiaz/nginx-http-json-log#how-to-build,

2.https://github.com/lindsayevans/nginx-json-status-module

I added these two  modules and followed the instructions.But I am still getting plain text logs.

Any idea for other solutions to log in JSON format from nginx or any changes in above two solutions?

Please paste your nginx.conf file also .

Answer (score 0):

here it is what you want.

```
worker_processes  4;
events {
    worker_connections  102400;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    log_format post_json escape=json $request_body;
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        location /log_json {
            return 200;
        }
        location / {
            if ($request_method != POST) {
                return 404;
            }
            access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/log_json.log post_json;
            proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1:$server_port/log_json;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```